# Cache-Control header did not work for images

Tags: php, caching, browser

I have a php script that severs a image by ID:

```
function setCacheHeader($seconds = 86400)
{
    $time = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds) . " GMT";
    header("Expires: $time");
    header("Pragma: cache");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=$seconds");
}

$file = "/xxx/xxx/" . intval($_GET['id']);

setCacheHeader();
header("Content-Type: image/jpg");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
```

And a nginx config to rewrite restful URL to this script:

```
location /images/ {
   rewrite /images/(\d+) /images.php?id=$1 last;
}
```

The cache header is sent correctly,

[image]

But the browser does not cache the content, I didn't see any 304 response, when I access the /images/ID url, it always return 200 instead. I tried multiple times, nothing changes.

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: If `200` is the status code of the cached resource, then that's what you'll see (depending on the specific developer tools you're using) when you retrieve it from the cache. `304` is a status code that's used for revalidation; that is, it's used *after* the cache time has expired, so is not what you should expect to see. So far you haven't shown any evidence that the resource isn't cached, so your next step is to get more detail from the developer tool, check server logs, etc. to see if there's really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your cache-control header seems to be working fine. The issue is with the expires header. When a browser gets conflicting data in the 2 headers it will use the earlier of the two TTLs to determine when to fetch new data.

It *would* have been useful if you had tested the code with a more unusual value than 86400 seconds (exactly one day) which might have given a more EXPLICIT indicator that the cache-control header was correct.

It is possible that something else is overwriting the Expires header. If this were my problem, my next step would be to add instrumentation in the code to log the data it is setting in the headers and compare these with what you are seeing at the browser, and testing the code on a minimal build environment.

BTW the Pragma header does nothing here.